# Scanf a Character into an Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, char, printf, scanf

I'm trying to take a single character in an array and then print that character using a specific syntax. Here's my code :

```
int main(){
char in[18];
scanf("%c",in);
printf("%c",in);
return 0;
}
```

I know how to take a character from user in C & many other ways to do the same task but I'm curious to know Why this code prints nothing on the screen. Here's my explanation for this code. Kindly correct me if wrong.

1. First of all array of 18 characters is declared.
2. Using `scanf`, Character is stored in the 1st position of array.("in" refers to the address of its first element.)
3. Then when I'm trying to print that character, It prints nothing.
4. When I changed "in" to "in[0]" then Character prints on the screen.
5. I think "in" also points to the 1st element as well as in[0] too. Then Why I'm getting two different answers. ?

Thanks In Advance !!

Comment: `in` **decays** to a `char *`. `printf` expects a `char`. So what do you think happens? `in` itself is an array, not a pointer!

Comment: I recently switched to C from Java. that's why did this stupid mistake. Thanks for clearing my doubt.

Comment: I'd recommend to read a good C book very carefully. There are a lot of different concepts between these languages. C does not prevent you from shooting your foot.

Comment: Would you please recommend some good books which helps me to understand the concepts deeply ?

Comment: Just see the C info page. I just use the standard, but that is hardly a good start for a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code invokes undefined behavior, the compiler might be warning about the fact that the `"%c"` specifier expects a `char` (*rigorously speaking it expects an `int` parameter that is after converted to `unsigned char`*) parameter but you passed a `char *` (*an array of `char`*).

To make it print the character use

```
printf("%c", in[0]);
```

Passing the wrong type for a given format specifier in both `printf()` and `scanf()` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

`in[0]` does not point to the first element in the array.  It **is** the first element in the array.

`in` has type `char *` (when passed to a function) while `in[0]` has type `char`.  And the `%c` format specifier to `printf` expects a `char`, not a `char *`.